# Does Google Analytics report on social media referrals?

Tags: google-analytics, facebook, social-media, twitter, instagram

I already know how to show device type that customer use when click link that contain gtag. Now I want to know which social media that customer uses when they click the link.

Example, I share my link that contain GTAG in a Facebook or Twitter post. When customer clicks it, I want Google Analytics to show Facebook or Twitter as the source that the link comes from.

In acquisition source, it only shows direct, none and Google, How to make it show Facebook, Twitter, and Instagram as the source? Or is there another report that shows that in Google Analytics?

Comment: Are you using Universal Analytics (UA) or Google Analytics 4 (GA4)?

Comment: I create both, but i use GA4 as the config in my webpage @StephenOstermiller

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you absolutely can without relying on UTM tags. In UA it's under Acquisition > Source / Medium, or GA4 it's either Acquisition > User Acquisition or Traffic Acquisition and change the dimension to either first user or session source / medium. This will show exactly which social media network lead the user to your website, just as it shows any other traffic sources.

The issue may arise if the user is linked to your website from a **social media app**. Depending on how the app operates, Analytics may not be able to recognise the referrer, leading the traffic to be flagged as direct. In this case, UTM tags added to the links you're posting on social media would be the best resolution.

UTM tags are very helpful in other ways; indicating which specific post and whether it was organic or paid/boosted.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to specifically track which social media platform a customer clicks a link from in Google Analytics. However, you can use UTM parameters to track this information.

Comment: That's absolutely not true.